# Why is my function outputting a hex number instead of an int?

Tags: visual-c++

I want to do a bubble sort for my array but I got an infinite loop, so I checked if my CheckSorting function is working correctly and instead I found it's outputting my variable inside called "errors" into a hex number even though my function is an int type and the variable is type int. How do I make my function return an integer instead?
Sorry if this isn't clear, I am very new to coding.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int GetInteger();
int IntegerCheck(int min, int max);

int CountOccurences(int theArray[], const int arraySize, int value);
void InputUniqueValues(int theArray[], const int arraySize, int min, int max);
void SortArray(int theArray[], const int arraySize, int min, int max);
int CheckSorting(int theArray[], const int arraySize); // change back to bool

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 10;
    const int MIN = 1;
    const int MAX = 50;
    int values[SIZE] {};
    
    cout << "Please enter 10 unique numbers, and I will sort them for you.\n";
    InputUniqueValues(values, SIZE, MIN, MAX);
    CheckSorting(values, SIZE);
    cout << CheckSorting << " errors in this order\n";
    cout << "Your numbers are sorted.\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (i < SIZE - 1)
        {
            cout << values[i] << ",  ";
        }
        else if (i == SIZE - 1)
        {
            cout << values[i] << "\n\n";
        }
    }
 
    return 0;
}

int GetInteger()
{
    int value = 0;
    while (!(cin >> value))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return value;
}

int IntegerCheck(const int min, const int max)
{
    int input = 0;

    do
    {
        input = GetInteger();

        if (input < min || input > max)
        {
            cout << "*error!* YOU MUST ENTER A NUMBER BETWEEN " << min << " and " << max << endl;
        }
    }
    while (input < min || input > max);

    return input;
}

int CountOccurences(int theArray[], const int arraySize, int value)
{
    int occurences = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        if (theArray[i] == value)
        {
            occurences++;
        }
    }

    return occurences;
}

void InputUniqueValues(int theArray[], const int arraySize, int min, int max)
{
    int uniqueValuesEntered = 0;
    int input = 0;
    int occurences = 0;

    //Keep looping until 10 unique values have been entered
    while (uniqueValuesEntered < arraySize)
    {
        //Read in the number
        input = IntegerCheck(min, max);
        occurences = CountOccurences(theArray, uniqueValuesEntered, input);

        //Is the number unique? If occurences == 0 then it is unique
        if (occurences == 0)
        {
            theArray[uniqueValuesEntered] = input;
            uniqueValuesEntered++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " * Error: " << input << " has already been entered, please enter a unique number. *\n";
        }
    }
}

void SortArray(int theArray[], const int arraySize, int min, int max)
{
    InputUniqueValues(theArray, arraySize, min, max);
    
    do
    {
        CheckSorting(theArray, arraySize);
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            cout << CheckSorting << endl;
            if (CheckSorting == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (theArray[i] > theArray[i++])
                {
                    int tempvalue = theArray[i];
                    theArray[i] = theArray[i++]; 
                    theArray[i++] = tempvalue;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            if (i < arraySize - 1)
            {
                cout << theArray[i] << ",  ";
            }
            else if (i == arraySize - 1)
            {
                cout << theArray[i] << "\n\n";
            }
        }
    }
    while(CheckSorting > 0);
}

int CheckSorting(int theArray[], const int arraySize)
{
    int errors = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < arraySize; j++)
        if (theArray[i] <= theArray[j])
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (theArray[i] > theArray[j])
        {
            cout << theArray[i] << " is > " << theArray[j] << endl;
            errors++;
        }
    }
        return errors;
}
```

Comment: `cout << CheckSorting << endl;` prints the address of the function `CheckSorting`. Addresses are customarily printed in hex. This is probably not what you had in mind. You may wish to review in your C++ textbook how to call a function and save its result in a variable. The use of a function name on its own doesn't mean "the return value this function produced when called most recently", as you appear to believe.